# How can I prevent the dwell clicker Point and Click from stealing the focus when I dictate with Dragon Professional Individual?

Tags: windows-10, accessibility, dragon-naturally-speaking, dwell-clicker

I use Dragon Professional Individual 15.6 and [Point-N-Click Virtual Mouse By Polital Enterprises](https://polital.com/pnc/) on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro. Point and Click keeps stealing the focus when I dictate, which stops the transcription. I have the same issue on all Win10 5 computers. I tried with Dragon 12.5, Dragon 15.3 and Dragon 15.6. I didn't have this issue with Microsoft Windows 7.

Here's the Point-N-Click that steals the focus after ~30 seconds of dictation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to automatically minimize the Point-N-Click window by selecting this icon:

[image]

[image]

The Point-N-Click window will then appears as a small floating icon:

[image]

This prevents Point-and-Click from stealing the focus when I dictate with Dragon Professional Individual.